# Add visual elements (icons) to ggpplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code that creates a bar plot using ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
    name=c("north","south","south-east","north-west","south-west","north-east","west","east"),
    val=sample(seq(1,10), 8 )
)

data %>%
    mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, val)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=name, y=val)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("") +
    theme_bw()
```

Is it possible to add some visual elementos to the plot, say for example next to "south" adding a small icon and the same for the other regions?

It would look like the attached image...

[image: example image]

Comment: What do you mean by icons? Like add them to the legend labels? I'm confused because what you've attached is just a legend.

Comment: I know there is a way to tie in `font-awesome`. Basically you're changing the font to one based on symbols instead of letters. Perhaps that helps in terms of a search.

Comment: Instead of getting just the label, you'll get the label and at the right side you'll get a square with a different color for every label. That's the difference in the picture you should see the legend text AND the icon or image